# Python AppIndicator to make tomate Unity compliant

Tags: gtk, pygtk, appindicator

I just discovered tomate : https://gitorious.org/tomate a very simple program that help get things done when you work on a computer.

But tomate use gtk.status_icon instead of appindicator so I would like to fix this.

However, I would like to keep the same behaviour with appindicator.
It is very easy to use like this and I don't whan to create a menu and complicate its use.

The simple behaviour is that when you click on the icon you start the time counter and when you click again you stop it.

So you don't need a menu.

Is it possible to use appindicator without a menu or with a basic menu that just receive the click and don't have any items?

Thank for you help.

Comment: Here is how I did using a menu : https://gitorious.org/~natim/tomate/natim-tomate it is not bad, but not as simple as the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the menu is what makes appindicator so different.

So basically, I just created a menu and change the way I update the menu and the icon.

```
diff -r 13c201b1030a tomate.py
--- a/tomate.py Fri May 13 19:48:31 2011 +0200
+++ b/tomate.py Wed May 18 09:26:43 2011 +0200
@@ -1,53 +1,79 @@
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 from __future__ import division

 import pygtk
 pygtk.require('2.0')
 import gtk
 import os
 from time import time
 from math import floor
 gtk.gdk.threads_init()
 import gobject
+import appindicator

 #Parameters
 MIN_WORK_TIME = 60 * 10 # min work time in seconds

 class Pomodoro:
     def __init__(self):
-        self.icon=gtk.status_icon_new_from_file(self.icon_directory()+"idle.png")
-        self.icon.set_tooltip("Idle")
+        self.ind = appindicator.Indicator("tomate","tomate", 
+                                       appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
+
+        self.ind.set_status (appindicator.STATUS_ACTIVE)
+        self.ind.set_icon(self.icon_directory()+"idle.png")
         self.state = "idle"
         self.tick_interval=10 #number of seconds between each poll
-        self.icon.connect('activate',self.icon_click)
-        self.icon.set_visible(True)
         self.start_working_time = 0
+        self.menu = gtk.Menu()
+        # Tooltip item
+        self.item = gtk.MenuItem('Idle')
+        self.item.connect("activate", self.icon_click, None)
+        self.item.show()
+        self.menu.append(self.item)
+        # A separator
+        separator = gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
+        separator.show()
+        self.menu.append(separator)
+        # A quit item
+        item = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
+        item.connect("activate", gtk.main_quit, None)
+        item.show()
+        self.menu.append(item)
+        self.menu.show_all()
+        self.ind.set_menu(self.menu)
     def format_time(self,seconds):
         minutes = floor(seconds / 60)
         if minutes > 1:
             return "%d minutes" % minutes
          else:
-            return "%d minute" % minutes
     def set_state(self,state):
         old_state=self.state
-        self.icon.set_from_file(self.icon_directory()+state+".png")
+        self.ind.set_icon(self.icon_directory()+state+".png")
         if state == "idle":
             delta = time() - self.start_working_time
             if old_state == "ok":
-                self.icon.set_tooltip("Good! Worked for %s." % 
+                self.item.get_child().set_text("Good! Worked for %s." % 
                         self.format_time(delta))
             elif old_state == "working":
-                self.icon.set_tooltip("Not good: worked for only %s." % 
+                self.item.get_child().set_text("Not good: worked for only %s." % 
                         self.format_time(delta))
         else:
             if state == "working":
                 self.start_working_time = time()
             delta = time() - self.start_working_time
-            self.icon.set_tooltip("Working for %s..." % self.format_time(delta))
+            self.item.get_child().set_text("Working for %s..." % self.format_time(delta))
         self.state=state
     def icon_directory(self):
         return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + os.path.sep
-    def icon_click(self,dummy):
+    def icon_click(self, *args):
         delta = time() - self.start_working_time
         if self.state == "idle":
             self.set_state("working")
@@ -59,7 +85,7 @@
         if self.state == "idle":
             pass
         else:
-            self.icon.set_tooltip("Working for %s..." % self.format_time(delta))
+            self.item.get_child().set_text("Working for %s..." % self.format_time(delta))
             if self.state == "working":
                 if delta > MIN_WORK_TIME:
                     self.set_state("ok")
```